# How to use ENTER as user input

Tags: r, for-loop, break, enter

I have a for loop and I want it to only go to the next "i"-value when you hit enter in the console. So I wrote this:

```
for (i in 1:5){
 print(i) 
 UserInput <- readline(prompt = "Press enter to continue.")
 if (UserInput != "ENTER"){ #Obviously "ENTER" is incorrect, but something like that. 
  break
 }
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using r. Added it to the tag now - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is:

```
for (i in 1:5){
    readline(prompt=i) }
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach will prompt the user to press enter, and will go to the next `i` when they do so:

```
for (i in 1:5){
    print(i) 
    readline(prompt = "Press Enter")
}
# [1] 1
# Press Enter
# [1] 2
# Press Enter
# [1] 3
# Press Enter
# [1] 4
# Press Enter
# [1] 5
# Press Enter
```

If you want the first result (1) to show only after an "enter", then just swap the two lines, `print` and `readline`.

Edit: based on comment, you can break if something other than an "enter" was input

```
for (i in 1:5){
  print(i) 
  input <- readline(prompt = "Press Enter")
  if(input != "") break
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to put that into an if-statement? Like, only if "enter" has been pressed it will move to the next "i"? So that I can exit it with user input other than "enter"?

Comment: Added an example above. Since an "enter" is just recorded as a `""` (blank character) you can do a simple test for not being a blank.

Comment: Yes. That's what I found worked too. Thanks a lot:)